# Which is harder to win? predicting a coin face or liar's dice

Tags: probability, dice

May I inquire as to which task poses a greater challenge?

The act of correctly predicting the outcome of a single coin toss.

**Versus**

Achieving victory in Liar's Dice when:

- **two players** are involved and each player has been provided with **two dice**.
- **two players** are involved and each player has been provided with **five dice**.
- **three players** are involved and each player has been provided with **five dice**.

The probability of predicting a single coin toss is **50%**. And the probability of winning in Liar's Dice also depends on the strategy of the players and their knowledge and experience. Assuming all players are engaged in a perfect play strategies at Liar's Dice and the coin tosses are fair.

So, which one is harder to predict?

**Edit**:

In addition, for comparison, please add the breakdown of the difficulty to predict between predicting the above-mentioned Liar's Dice event and rolling a single die, which has a probability of **1/6**.

There are some reference links to the rules of Liar's Dice:

- [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar's_dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar%27s_dice)
- https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs109l/unrestricted/assignments/assn1a/liarsdice.pdf

Comment: This is too vague, could you add some formalism?

Comment: Since the probability of winning in Liar's Dice depends on the strategies of other players, maybe you can make your question more specific by adding more constraints, such as: "all players engage in perfect play", or any other predetermined strategy. This will make your question more answerable.

Comment: I have added the constraints, all players are engaged in perfect play strategies at Liar's Dice.

Comment: Might be useful to include a link to the rules for Liar's Dice. Does [this Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar%27s_dice) provide the rules you need?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll include some reference links to the rules of Liar's Dice.

Comment: Well, if the game is fair, then each player has an equal chance of winning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By symmetry, the chance of winning any N-player game where all players play perfectly, no ties are allowed, and the player order is randomized, is 1/N. No advantage can be given by strategy since all players play perfectly (meaning identically, given their seat), and any advantage/disadvantage given by player order is exactly balanced out by the fact that the player order is randomized. The probabilities of the first/second/third player winning are ultimately irrelevant when the player order is assigned randomly, since the overall win probability is averaged over player positions and always comes out to 1/N.

If we randomize the player order and everybody plays perfectly, you have a 50% chance of winning the 2-player game, and a 33% chance of winning the 3-player game. It doesn't matter what the game is, so long as there are no ties.

Comment: Suggestion: replace "identically" by "optimally".

Comment: @Piita I'm trying to highlight that each player would make the exact same decision when faced with a particular game state. If Person A has a 70% chance of winning when being player 1, so too does Person B when they sit there. Person B must play the same as Person A from that seat, or else one of them isn't playing optimally. No player can gain an advantage when having to play from a random seat, since they're all using *the same* optimal strategy.

Comment: I understood that. My point is that your answer is meant to cover the *genre* rather than a specific game, and that some games in this genre allow for different lines of play with same EV, so  "identically" is wrong imo. Players do not necessarily take the exact same decisions in certain game states.

Comment: Oh... so in Liar's Dice, assuming all players are engaged in a perfect play strategy at Liar's Dice, if there are two players involved and each player has provided with two - five dice, the chance will be 50%, similar to predicting outcome of a single coin toss. If there are three players involved and each player has thrown two to five dice, the chance is 33.33%, more difficult than predicting the outcome of a single coin toss. Think that's right?

Comment: Therefore, I think it could be risky if players engage in perfect game strategy in Liar's Dice as a gambling tool because the odds are 50% (similar to predicting the outcome of a single coin toss) and 33.33% if three players are involved. And the risk is even worse if a novice player plays Liar's Dice against another player who has an optimal strategy. Correct?

Comment: I mean, the factors that will make gambling have the potential to lose money, like the risk of betting an unreasonable amount of money (large enough to be wasted) and wasting them in a relatively short amount of time and possibly without proper knowledge and calculation of the probability of the game?

Comment: In this Liar's Dice scenario, if two players engage in a perfect game strategy, the odds are 50% (similar to a fair coin toss), so we have a 50% probability of winning, but also have a 50% probability of losing, and the odds will decrease if there are more players, and even worse if the players don't have good enough knowledge of the probabilities and strategies in the game.